# Are there any high level, simple IPC libraries

Tags: c#, ipc

Are there any high level, simple IPC libraries for C#? It seems most posts point to using WCF. But this looks far more complicated than I need. I just want to send asynchronous messages between two C# apps that may or may not be on the same system.

I am hoping something exists that is as simple to use as the following which comes down to just a Send and an OnRead command. (Link is the IPC library I hope exists).

```
private void StartServer()
{
    using (var link = new Link("InstanceName"))
    {
        link.OnRead += delegate(Link client, object data)
                           {
                               client.Send("Echoing " + data);
                           };
        link.Connect();
        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to stop the server.");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

private void StartClient()
{
    using (var link = new Link("serverName", "InstanceName"))
    {
        link.OnRead += delegate(Link server, object data) { Console.WriteLine(data); };
        link.Connect();
        link.Send("Hello There!");
        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to stop the client.");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: take a look at [MessageBus](http://matrixplatform.com/index.php?title=Framework.MessageBus)

Answer (score 1):

Self-hosted WCF would come close.

Comment: From what I've seen WCF requires a lot of configuration setting up endpoints and service contracts. That is what I am hoping to avoid.

Comment: Somewhat true but a lot is generated for you and WCF4 adds  a lot of default mechanisms. But I'm not really sure what the minimum for peer-to-peer is.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at our [MsgConnect](http://www.eldos.com/msgconnect/) which offers exactly what you need and for many platforms including .NET. Design of MsgConnect is inspired by Windows API - PostMessage/SendMessage/GetMessage functions, yet MsgConnect has Socket transport which lets you send messages across network. Samples are available in the installation package.